# How to prevent two lists in python from synching in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have narrowed down the problem this much. I have a list [1, 3, 2, 1] and I am looking to store that list in a variable, remove one item index 2 and store the result in another variable. This is the code:

```
sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1]

temporary_list = sequence

del temporary_list[2]

print(sequence)
print(temporary_list)
```

However both sequence and `temporary_list` print the same values (`[1, 3, 1]`). What am I doing wrong? What would be the right way to get `[1, 3, 2, 1]` and `[1, 3, 1]`?

Comment: Create a copy e.g. `temporary_list = sequence.copy()`, otherwise you just have 2 references pointing to the same unique object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2.x:
temporary_list = sequence[:]

If python 3.x:

Temporary_list = sequency.copy()

Python assigned objects are just a binding between a target and a object, if you want a new object you must "copy" it to create a new object. Look at the official docs for more info:https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html